# File read gets EOF before real EOF

Tags: python, image, eof

I receive a file (*.png) via network and that file is written (in binary mode) to the HDD properly.

When I try to open the file, for further manipulation, it won't load totally corrupting the lower part of the png image. This happens with several PNG files so it's not an isolated case.

```
#File received a properly written to HDD
fp = open(os.path.join(self.savedir, filename), 'wb')
fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
print fp.tell()             # prints correct size, in this case: 343661bytes
fp.close

# Reads the data in the file but not till the real EOF
fin = open(os.path.join(self.savedir, filename), 'rb')
data = fin.read()
print len(data)              # prints 339968
print fin.tell()             # prints correct size, in this case: 339968bytes
fin.close
```

I'm using python 2.7.9, both on linux(64bits) and window(32bits) the behaviors is the same on both machines. These code snipeds where in different functions, now are as shown above next to each other for sanity check. Obviously the file is only handled by this program and there are no concorrent threads of anyone dealing with the file.

Comment: Why are you using `decode=True`? If it's binary stream, shouldn't you just write it as is?

Comment: This can't be your real code, because it'll just raise an `IndentationError`.

Comment: It's better to open files with [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) (see end of section for example). This makes sure the file is closed properly.

Comment: @PeterWood: The reason I brought up the IndentationError is because, seeing everything indented over the `open`, my brain just assumed there was a `with` statement without reading it, so I almost didn't spot the mistake. :)

Comment: @abarnert same here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not closing the file. This line:

```
fp.close
```

… just references the `close` method as a value, it doesn't call it.

So, when you open the same file in read mode, the last buffer usually won't have been flushed to disk yet. Of course when the program exits, then the buffer usually gets flushed (although this isn't guaranteed…), so when you go check the file it looks perfectly fine. It just wasn't perfectly fine yet when your code tried to read it.

You need parentheses to call anything in Python:

```
fp.close()
```

Or, better, use a `with` statement instead of explicit `close()`.

Comment: Simply did not noticed that. Change all file IO in the code to "with" to avoid these kind of errors.